# How to get my own facebook/twitter wall status using CS5.5?

Tags: facebook, flash, twitter, adobe, status

i'm trying to learn how to get my own facebook & twitter wall status into flash so that I can export it out and install it in my iPhone.
After reading the facebook and twitter API documentation, I'm still very confussed on how to use them.
I'm very new to this and hope to get a suitable tutorial/sample code for some reference.

Help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Using the Facebook API is like putting your privates into a meat mixer while pouring acid on your own head and standing in a bucket full of meat ants while listening to a live performance of "Friday" by Rebecca Black.

Comment: im very doubful some one will give you an example because what your asking is to basically a completed sample. are you familiar with flash, are you able to communicate php with flash at all if not start there.have you got some code you can post in your question or havent you started at all, it helps to know where your having the problem thats all

Comment: No help.  It's Friday, so only fun, fun, fun, fun.  Tomorrow is Saturday, and Sunday comes afterwards.

Comment: Heehee; but seriously the Facebook API is terrible, and what you're trying to do without any evidence of an attempt is less achievable than driving a car into a wall at 240kmph and surviving.

Comment: agreed, your best bit is to try to communicate with facebook with php if you can achieve a connection try to print your specified results than after worry about flash, if you got something throw it in your answer and im sure we will help.

Comment: Yes. All of you are right, facebook API is too difficult for me to understand. Plus I cant find any working samples around for facebook API in Flash AS3.

Comment: Now, parele mentioned that I can use php to communicate with facebook. How? Any online samples/ your own version of code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Twitter it is easy. Just write the AS3 code to load the Twitter user RSS as XML. After that you will be able to use it.

```
var myXmlLoader:Loader = new Loader();
myXmlLoader.load(new URLRequest("http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline/@twitterUser.rss"));

// just replace "twitterUser" with your twitter user, leave all the rest as is

myXmlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, xmlLoadCompleted);
function xmlLoadComplete(evt){
    var myWallData:XML = new XML(evt.target.data);
    trace(myWallData); // you will get an RSS XML with the last 20 tweets from your account
}
```

To get an RSS from your Facebook wall you can use this:
https://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?id=**23749877160**&format=rss20
where **23749877160** is your Facebook account ID

that will give you an rss with your Facebook just as twitter does,

But you need some trick to load it with flash.
Locally you can load it and it works good using the same code to load the twitter,
but on the web your swf wont be able to load, some crossdomain issue.

To fix this what I did is a simple PHP file to load the rss and save a file with the loaded content.

PHP code:

```
<?php

set_time_limit(300); // this is to set the time limit to execute a code, is that the facebook wall take too long to load

$fbURL = "https://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?id=23749877160&format=rss20";
$fileName = "myFileName.xml"; // the name you want to do to your file, the file you will load with flash

$doc = new DOMDocument();

if($doc->load( $fbURL )){
    $doc->save($fileName); // saving file in server folder
    }else{
       echo "error";
       }
?>
```

This is cool but you need to execute the PHP file before intent to load the generated XML.  you can use this code to do the trick

AS3 code:

```
var myPHPLoader:Loader = new Loader();
    myPHPLoader.load(new URLRequest("xmlGenerator.xml"));
    myPHPLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, phpLoaded);

function phpLoaded(evt){
 trace("PHP executed");
 // do whatever you want
 // after the php is executed you can load the fbXml generated normally 
 }
```

This works good, but keep in mind that the twitter rss  and Facebook RSS, has a call limit per hour (150 call) for twitter, for Facebook I dont know. so if your app reach that limit before complete the hour it will call the empty xml or an error.

dont worry for Facebook in this example you have an PHP that will save the file just if it loads good, if the PHP dont loads the Facebook wall then it wont save the file, so your app will load the old fbXml.

Use the same php to load the twitter rss and save a file to be loaded from your flash app.

What I did is the follow.

PHP Code:

```
<?php

function savePlainRss($loadURL, $fileName){
    set_time_limit(300);    
        $doc = new DOMDocument();

    if($doc->load( $loadURL)){
        $doc->save($fileName);
        }
    }

savePlainRss("https://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?id=23749877160&format=rss20", "myFacebookWall.xml");

savePlainRss("http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline/@twitterUser.rss", "myTwitterRSS.xml");

?>
```

This code will save an XML file for twitter rss and Facebook Wall but just if it can load it, if dont it will keep the old file.

Then from flash load the generated XML files.

For me to be sure my app wont reach the call limit and avoid twitter or facebook tag my app as spam, I did a cronjob on my Server to execute the PHP file
each 15 minutes so the calls to twitter and Facebook per hour is just 4, you can find help in google about how to do a cronjob, some hosting and web server have tools to do it.

you can do de calls each 5 minutes if you want more frequently updates or less, but keep in mind that the facebook load can take a long time, up to 300 seconds (5 minutes) dond use less than that to be sure you will have the complete work done.

Thanks for reading.
I hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

had alook at it: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web/ look here for the API.
i dont want to post there code on here...

Also heres seems to have more info:
http://facebook-actionscript-api.googlecode.com/svn/release/current/docs/index.html

this is successful with actionScript, i learned something new
if i got time i will create a basic user status or something and let you know, for now i hoped i pushed you in the right direction.